# Why does this react component from rendering test fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following test file for react:

```
  1 import React from 'react';
  2 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
  4 import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
  5 import { App } from './App';
  6
  7 it('renders without crashing', () => {
  8   const div = document.createElement('div');
  9   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
 10 });
 11
 12 it('renders 4 <LinkContainer />', () => {
 13   const appWrapper = mount(<App />);
 14   expect(appWrapper.find(LinkContainer)).to.have.length(4)
 15 });
```

Here is a portion of my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, Grid, Media, Navbar, NavItem, Nav, Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {


render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar fixedTop inverse>
          <Grid>
            <Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Brand>
                <Link to="/">Daniel Rubio</Link>
              </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Nav pullRight>
              <LinkContainer to="/about">
                <NavItem>About</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/education">
                <NavItem>Education</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/experience">
                <NavItem>Experience</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/skills">
                <NavItem>Skills</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Grid>
        </Navbar>
        <div className="contents">
          { this.props.children }
        </div>
        <Navbar fixedBottom inverse>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <p>Made with React and with EMCAScript6</p>
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this test, the second test fails with this error:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js


 ✓ renders without crashing (24ms)
  ✕ renders 4 <LinkContainer /> (21ms)

  ● renders 4 <LinkContainer />

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:14:93)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Test Summary
 › Ran all tests related to changed files.
 › 1 test failed, 1 test passed (2 total in 1 test suite, run time 0.476s)
```

I am following along the `Jest` tutorial and `Enzyme` tutorial found here[Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) . What I'm basically doing is pretyt much just copying how enzyme covers testing. However, it looks like react cannot find my `<LinkContainer />` component. I've required it from the appropriate package so it should be present right? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect()` from [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#writing-assertions-with-expect) does not include any `.to` property/matcher.

That's the reason why you are getting `undefined` when you are doing `expect(...).to.have`

That tutorial is using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [chai](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) as you can read in their [github page](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#enzyme)

> The documentation and examples for enzyme use mocha and chai, but you
>   should be able to extrapolate to your framework of choice.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Simply using `npm install chai` resolved my issue and then requiring it.